# create Scrollview programmatically c# iOS

Tags: c#, ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

i'm trying to create a scrollview dynamically in a xamarin.ios project
i'm create the scrollview in this way

```
var scrollView = new UIScrollView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height));
currentView.Add(scrollView);
```

then i want to put some ImageView (dynamically) in the scrollview here is the code

```
scrollView.Add(list_imgView[i]);
```

this array:

```
list_imgView[]
```

is a list of imgview.

in the ios simulator it displays the images but when i click and drag on my trackpad it doesn't scroll.
where is the error?

**EDIT**

if i put a color to my scrollView in this way

```
scrollView.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(10, 20, 30, 40);
```

it doesn't appear in my view anything colored.

Answer (score 0):

Usually issues with scrolling in a ScrollView are because of the content size in my experience. Try something like this where you add the image view to the scroll view:

```
scrollView.ContentSize = list_imgView[i].Image.Size;
scrollView.AddSubView(list_imgView[i]);
```

Comment: Looks like a possible issue with the UIScrollView's size then. It does seem kind of odd... I think normally you should set it to the View's frame size like this:  `var scrollView = new UIScrollView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));`

Comment: now, the scrollview has is own color, but it doesn't scroll anyway @rmc00

Comment: Hmm that's odd. It looks good to me at this point. My only suggestion is to check out the xamarin example. I know it's not much, but hopefully this helps or someone else sees another issue. https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/scroll_view/use_a_scrollview/